# Reopen "How to deal with a manager who does not respect me?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

The question [How to deal with a manager who does not respect me?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/58233/how-to-deal-with-a-manager-who-does-not-respect-me) was recently closed. After some discussion, it looked like it was on track to being reopened (3 votes last I saw). Unfortunately, another user hijacked the comments thread for their own purposes, resulting in the question becoming locked. Now I no longer can see the reopen count, which I'm guessing is a result of the question being locked.

I think this is a good question that is not a duplicate of the one linked in comments. It is a disservice to the OP that the question became locked before being reopened because of the actions of another user. Is there a way that we can allow the question to get some reopen votes while still closing the comments section?

Also, as a somewhat side note, the question was locked and encouraged discussion to move to chat, but there was never a room-specific chat room opened or linked. I think this should have been the first step before shutting down the question entirely.

Comment: FYI, I locked it (temporarily, for an hour) since... it had 50+ comments in total and was accumulating several comments a minute at its current rate.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. More of a "cool down" period than a permanent lock down. I was just surprised you didn't go for the "Let's continue this in chat" first.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for bringing this up on meta.

As noted by enderland in a comment, the question was locked for an hour due to an extremely high velocity of comments that weren't about improving the post.  Basically, we needed a "time-out" to try to move things in a more constructive direction after milder interventions had failed.  The lock has now expired and the (edited) question has been reopened.

It's unfortunate that we don't have a "lock comments" option; the only way to prevent more argumentative comments (which were coming in at several per minute) was to lock the whole post, which also locks votes of all types.  Locks like this are meant to be temporary, to stop the immediate problem and give people time to chill.  Now we'll see if that worked.

The question accumulated more than 50 comments.  I handled the first flag (about 17 hours ago) and considered moving comments to chat then, but many of the ones I deleted were not very constructive (and some borderline rude).  My judgement was that moving the thread to chat was unlikely to help the OP, a first-time poster, and there was no point in doing so otherwise.  Every participant in the discussion has enough reputation to use chat and could have used the site's main chat room to continue the discussion.  There was a second round of deletions a few hours ago (by more than one moderator) -- complaints from one user about prior deletions and responses to those complaints, and some obsolete comments about edits to the question, that ended in what you described as the "hijacking" and then the lock.

If the OP wants access to those comments for the purpose of further improving the question, I can provide that.  I think everything that could be gleaned has already been gleaned, but let me know if you'd like access, @Dom.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. When I posted I wasn't sure how permanent the "locked" status would be, so I wanted to bring it up. As of now it looks like the question has gotten enough votes to be reopened. Now hopefully it can get some good answers!

Comment: Oh, did the lock notice not show timing information to you?  (We mods see something like "expires in N minutes", but I didn't think to test that in an incognito window.)  That's good to know.  And yes, it's reopened now; I cast the fifth vote.

Comment: No, I don't think it gave any timing information. From what I remember it said that it was locked, by whom, and the reason (in this case too many comments, so continue in chat).